# Deploy Net core 5.0 API failed on Heroku with Docker Error: Unable to start Kestrel

Tags: docker, heroku, .net-core, kestrel

I try to Deploy Net core 5.0 API on Heroku and get this error:
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.FormatException: Invalid url: '3689' the number "3689" changes any time that deploy a new version of my API.

this is my docker file:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
 WORKDIR /src
 COPY Sporteate.API.csproj .
 RUN dotnet restore
 COPY . .
 RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY --from=build-env /app .
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sporteate.API.dll"]
 CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet Sporteate.API.dll
```

this is my program file:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
            log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()), log4netConfig["log4net"]);
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuldier =>
           {
               var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
               webBuldier.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls("http://*:" + port!=null? port : "44308");
           });

}
```

and this is my Heroku's dynos configuration:

```
 web /bin/sh -c ASPNETCORE_URLS\=http://\*:\$PORT\ dotnet\ Sporteate.API.dll
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi, I didn't find it.